# Running sed within R: Take random value and put into system() command

Tags: r, sed

I would like to generate a random value using `runif()` and then insert it into a `sed` command using `system()`. Can you think of a solution? Thank you.

Comment: 1) Edit your question to add information, don't comment on yourself. 2) Add a sample input and expected output, I'm pretty sure no-one there has divination skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a file called `hello` with contents "hello"

```
x = runif(1)
exe = paste0("sed 's/hello/", x, "/' hello")
exe
 [1] "sed 's/hello/0.572675835574046/' hello"
system(exe)
 0.572675835574046
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a problem with escape characters:
`Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string`. Inserting a \ prevents the error, but my output is not executable.

Comment: @rkay please post this as a new question and include command lines so that your example is reproducible

Comment: you just need to escape the '\' character like you always have to do in R
(mostly commenting for people finding this page)