# R-Read in csv files from PurpleAir sensors and skip error location where non standard characters are contained at the end of some rows

Tags: r, csv

I have a number of PurpleAir sensors that save one .csv file per day to a SD card with the date used as the file name. I am trying to extract and combine the data from each of these daily .csv files.

The data in the final cell of some rows for some reason is followed by 3 non standard characters and appears this way in the .csv file : 0.46
[Screenshot of characters because they are not showing up as text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4LM.png)

read.csv("filepath") - reads in the header line and all rows up to the first occurrence of these non standard characters correctly and then doesn't load the remaining data. If the error is in the first few rows the function gives the following error:

```
Warning message:
In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on '20200825.csv'
```

Manually opening the file and deleting these extra characters allows R to read in correctly down to the next row where these character appears (these characters appear in seemingly random rows but always at the end of a line / in the final cell).

I do not need the data from the final column so is there a way to tell the function to ignore the final column and just read in the first columns?

I have tried a number of suggestions from multiple threads but cannot solve the issue so far. Manually opening files and removing the characters is not an option as I have many files.

(Of note, attempting to read in as text with readLines and fix the characters just leads to the function ending when it encounters these characters the same as read.csv)

Seriously appreciate any support!

Comment: There is a colClasses parameter.

Comment: I have tried to use colClasses to ignore the last column with it set to "NULL". However, as these characters seem to be affecting the end of line, the function still stops at the end of that line. So skipping columns is maybe not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem too. The following line of R code takes care of the non-standard characters and also adds a newline character at the end of the last line if needed (this was also needed for some of my PurpleAir data) and writes it to a new file that R can read in without problems:

```
system(paste0("cat '", fname, "' | tr -d '\32' | sed '$a\\' > '", new_fname, "'"))
```

where fname is `"path-to-file/filename.csv"` and `new_fname` is `"path-to-newfile/newfilename.csv"`

References:

- [Running sed within R: Take random value and put into system() command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311591/running-sed-within-r-take-random-value-and-put-into-system-commandp_10_0_um_b)
- https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/108908-removing-z-character-file.html
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/how-to-add-a-newline-to-the-end-of-a-file

However, this is not an elegant solution. If someone has a better one that does not involve writing new files (or writing over the old files - I definitely don't want to do that), I am interested! Thanks for any advice you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "C")` before reading your csv file. I had a similar file and it worked by changing locale. If it doesn't work you can try changing to some other locale.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried the command above but unfortunately without success.